# Reading a uploaded text file and inserting into database

Tags: java, servlets

I am uploading a text file using servlets and reading it, and trying to insert into database

```
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        String path = context.getRealPath(file);
        File file = new File(path);
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath+File.separator+file.getName());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(strLine);
                decodeAisData(strLine); //it is reading each line but not inserting into database
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

In the decode i have written the database insertion logic, but it is not executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like path of file is incorrect while reading, did you try
 `in = new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath + File.separator+file1.getName());` ? or better get the stream from Classloader using getResourceAsStream(), more information can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Comment: Try using getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(), details information is provided  here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream

Comment: Where are you getting Null Pointer? Your stack trace should provide you enough information to locate exact line

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
atcom.journaldev.servlet.FileUploadServlet.doGet(FileUploadServlet.java:112)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: What is line 112 in FileUploadServlet.java ?

Comment: in.close(); i kept is.close();

Comment: if you are getting NPE at in.close() then looks like the NPE is thrown at in = new FileInputStream(file1.getName()) line due to which in variable never gets initialized and throws NPE at finally block

Comment: I have initialized the variable in with null value

Comment: If its printing each line but not inserting in DB, then looks like there is a bug in decodeAisData() method.